PWA - App shortcut only displayed when app is active
I've got a little progressive web app for recipes which I want to enhance with app shortcuts. Its built with vue & vite and vites pwa plugin. Adding the shortcut is straight forward.
I've tested the app on different devices. On my macos desktop using chrome the app shortcuts are displayed if the app is open (left picture) but not if it has been closed (right picture). Is this a desired behaviour? If not, how to fix it?


